# After inserting m2 ssd only grub is starting but not Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, ssd

I have Ubuntu(20.xx) on a 250gb ssd and MS-Windows on another 250gb ssd. As soon as I insert a 1tb m2 ssd in the motherboard (which had previously ubuntu 18.xx installed), ubuntu would not start, only the gnu grub is opening.

In the past the 2 ubuntu-s  worked fine along side each other, I was thinking that the m2 ssd was not formatted right so I tried something, still no success.

If you need more information just ask.

Thank you for your help already.

SOLVED: I just checked my motherboard and if I insert the m2 ssd the sata-port connection gets blocked so grub can not find the sata ssd. Thank you for helping

Comment: Can you tell which grub is running? And you said that you tried something.

Comment: it sayes grub version 2.04, i just formatted the m2 ssd multiple times in different fromats

Comment: I was wondering which one not which version: which of the two SSDs it is from. How did you "format" the m2 ssd?

Comment: By default, when Ubuntu installs GRUB, GRUB is configured to look for its configuration files in Ubuntu's /boot/grub directory. It looks like the M2 SSD contains a GRUB not configured for the new setup. You can use https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/ to boot into Ubuntu, then run `grub-install` and `update-grub`.

Comment: it is on the 250gb sata ssd, i tried in the win 10 Disk management i deleted everything and made it fat, exfat ...., in the macOS Disk Utility and also so in the macOS terminal but i do not remember the command, thanks for replying

Comment: @Hermann I still can boot into Ubuntu if I deinstall the m2 ssd (the hardware), can I run commands you mention in ubuntu without useing supergrub2?

Comment: @Hermann if i ru grub-install, I get this output : grub-install: Attention: Disk does not exist, partition of device /dev/sda2 is used instead., so how can i do this?

Comment: My theory is that there is a mis-configured GRUB stored on the M2 SSD. You cannot fix it if it is not connected to the system. You can run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdwhatever` to install GRUB to that particular storage device. Alternatively, you can always configure your BIOS/UEFI to boot from the old SSD.